# How to write a formula to to say if record types XYZ is new/created with the origin of email or web or phone then send email alert?

Tags: case, email-alert, recordtriggeredflow

Im trying to create a flow that sends an auto response when a new case is created. As my start criteria I decided to use a formula. I an getting errors with my syntax. im trying to say if record types XYZ is new/created with the origin of email or web or phone then send email alert. Please see formula:

```
(
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status}, "New")
    &&
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Origin}, "Email")
    ||
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Origin}, "Web")
    ||
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Origin}, "Phone")
)
&&
(
    {!$Record.RecordTypeId} = "012Db000003XyyNIAS"
    /* Standard */
    ||
    {!$Record.RecordTypeId} = "012Db000003XyyDIAS"
    /* Merchant */
    ||
    {!$Record.RecordTypeId} = "012Db000003XyxyIAC"
    /* Donor */
)
```

Comment: Quick tip for this site: You can highlight a section of code (or a formula in this case) and then click the `{}` button to format it as code. Highlighting then pressing `ctrl` + `k` does the same thing. Alternatively, you can put 3 backticks `\`\`\`` on their own line right above and below the thing you want to format as a "code block". That (and appropriate indentation) generally makes things like this a lot easier to read.

Comment: Also, exactly what error message are you getting? Please just copy/paste the error when you [edit] your question (as trying to shorten or paraphrase it means you're probably leaving out important information).